# Force HTTPS 301 redirect with hook

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, redirect, template-redirect

I am trying to force a 301 https redirect with hooking into the 'template redirect' function. I want not doing it a htaccess because when I update my permalinks, htaccess with https redirect disappears.

So with this function I want to do a redirect if the url is loaded with 'http', but nothing happens. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bhww_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );
function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_ssl() && !is_admin() ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
            exit();
        } else {
            wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add https in very simple way.... No need to had code all these in any hook....

1. Log in to wordpress admin
2. Go to Settings > General
3. Find WordPress Address (URL) and Replace HTTP with HTTPS
4. Find Site Address (URL) and Replace HTTP with HTTPS
5. Click **Save Changes**

Edit .htaccess file and add bellow code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^huepixel\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.huepixel.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Install wordpress-https Plugin and configure it....

That's All

Comment: Have done that, but my Wordpress doesn't redirect automatically..

Comment: Its working fine for me....
Here is my domain
https://www.huepixel.com/

Comment: You mean it works with the wordpress-https plugin or with no plugin at all?

Comment: I used wordpress-https plugin

Comment: I have activated the plugin too and it works! Thanks